# How do I represent a json array within the data parameter in a jquery ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to post [some data via ajax](http://jsfiddle.net/g1wvryp7/) to our backend API, but the arrays within the json data get turned into weird things by jquery...for example, the backend (python) sees the jquery ajax data as a dict of two lists

```
{'subject': ['something'], 'members[]': ['joe','bob']}
```

when it should be

```
{'subject':'something','members':['joe','bob']}
```

The HTML Form extracted from a react component:

```
  <div class="the_form">
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <input type="textarea" ref="members" placeholder="spongebob, patrick" />
      <input type="submit" value="Add Thread" />
    </form>
  </div>
```

The jquery ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            // csrf validation
        },
        url: this.props.url,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {subject: "something", members: ["joe","bob"]},
        success: function(data) {
          this.setState({data: data});
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
          console.log(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
});
```

I am able, however, to make such a request appropriately with httpie (simple http command line client):

```
echo '{"subject":"something", "members":["joe","bob"]}' | http  --auth test:test POST localhost:8000/api/some_page/ --verbose
```

What might I be doing wrong in the javascript request such that the inputs come into the server differently than expected?

Comment: _"What might I be doing wrong"_ I don't know, why don't you show us your code instead of making us guess?

Comment: Post HTML structure for the form and how you make AJAX request.

Comment: Show your complete code which you are processing to get this output.

Comment: Make sure your content type header is application/json and you are not doing form post

Comment: hat tip @mecek: I needed `contentType: 'application/json'`

Answer (score 1):

Try to stringify your object before calling your ajax function

`JSON.stringify({subject: "something", members: ["joe","bob"]})`

Comment: this was also needed, but I needed to add `contentType: 'application/json'` as well

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
data: {subject: "something", members: ["joe","bob"]},
```

Then in backend

```
request.POST.getlist('members[]')
```

**IF you want to use `application/json` as `contentType`.Then try this**

```
data: JSON.stringify({subject: "something", members: ["joe","bob"]}),
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

In backend,

```
json.loads(request.body)['members']
```